# autocad .net CreateFromCurves() Invalid input

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, region

I am trying to create a region from a Polyline3d but the method **Region.CreateFromCurves(curvesSegments)** in my code return invalid input error. I have been scratching my head for nearly 3 days but found no reasonable explanation for this issue. Here are the snip set of codes which generate error:

```
    Point3dCollection _border = new Point3dCollection();
    double _radius;
    Vector3d _normal

    // some codes to input value to _radius, _normal

    // creating a hexagon border here that contains 6 coplanar points
     public void CreateBorder()
    {
        _border.Clear();
        Vector3d vect = new Vector3d(_radius, 0, 0);
        for (int index = 0; index < _count; index++)
        {
            _border.Add (_center + vect);
            vect = vect.RotateBy(_angle, _normal);
        }
    }

    public Region CreateTopBottom(bool isBottom)
    {
        Polyline3d poly = new Polyline3d(Poly3dType.SimplePoly, _border, true);
        DBObjectCollection curves = new DBObjectCollection();
        curves.Add(poly);
        DBObjectCollection regions = Region.CreateFromCurves(curves);
        regions Region region = regions[0] as Region;
        if (!isBottom) region.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(_normal * _height));
        return region;
    }
```

I suspect that the compiler consider my points in _border (a Point3dCollection) are not coplanar, thus it results in the error. However, my points, as you can see, are perfectly coplanar, but I don't know how to "inform" the compiler that. Is my suspect correct? How can I fix this? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your should use a Polyline (and a Point2dCollection) instead.

```
    Point2dCollection _border = new Point2dCollection();
    Vector3d _normal;
    int _count;
    Point3d _center;
    double _radius;
    double _height;
    Plane _plane; // new Plane(Point3d.Origin, _normal)

    public void CreateBorder()
    {
        Point2d center = _center.Convert2d(_plane);
        double angle = 2 * Math.PI / _count;
        _border.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
        {
            double a = i * angle;
            _border.Add(new Point2d(center.X + _radius * Math.Cos(a), center.Y + _radius * Math.Sin(a)));
        }
    }

    public Region CreateTopBottom(bool isBottom)
    {
        Region region = null;
        double elevation = _center.TransformBy(Matrix3d.WorldToPlane(_plane)).Z;
        using (Polyline pline = new Polyline(_border.Count))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _border.Count; i++)
            {
                pline.AddVertexAt(i, _border[i], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            }
            pline.Closed = true;
            pline.TransformBy(Matrix3d.PlaneToWorld(_plane));
            pline.Elevation = isBottom ? elevation : elevation + _height;
            var curves = new DBObjectCollection() { pline };
            var regions = Region.CreateFromCurves(curves);
            region = (Region)regions[0];
        }
        return region;
    }
```

But what's wrong in your code is the way you build the Point3dCollection (_border).
You have to transform the Vector3d(_radius, 0, 0) so that it's perpendicular to the _normal vector.
A Vector3d is immutable, so the Vector3d.TransformBy() method has no side effect and return a new Vector3d. You have to redefine vect with this value.

```
public void CreateBorder()
{
    double angle = 2 * Math.PI / _count;
    _border.Clear();
    Plane plane = new Plane(Point3d.Origin, _normal);
    Vector3d vect = new Vector3d(_radius, 0.0, 0.0).TransformBy(Matrix3d.PlaneToWorld(plane));
    for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
    {
        _border.Add(_center + vect);
        vect = vect.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Rotation(angle, _normal, Point3d.Origin));
    }
}
```

Comment: the reasons I want to use Point3dCollection are 1. The other codes can be benefit from this and 2. I want to apply this to a jigging process with dynamic normal vector. Is there a way to use the Point3dCollection, or must I use the Point2dCollection and then transform the region accordingly (this way I have to do a lot of work for the other codes)?

Comment: i edited my reply trying to explain what was wrong in the way you built the Point3dCollection. You can probably use the corrected CreateBorder() method with your previous code to create the region from a Polyline3d. You can also create a Polyline by converting each Point3d into a Point2d.

Comment: thank you for explaining the normal vector problem. That's exactly what causing my code to sometime crashes, sometime produces unexpected results without me noticing.